# Is anyone use SML or OCaml for building real world GUI?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, sml, ml

After looking at some OCaml graphics related [projects](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/humps/caml_Graphics_and_GUI_tool_kits.html) it seems that no one using it for building GUI.

- why ?
- is there any modern alternatives to those outdated libraries ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My colleagues and I use OCaml to build iOS apps that we sell. Everything is coded in OCaml, including the GUI. However, making a full OCaml binding to Cocoa Touch would be a very large undertaking, so we concentrate on building the parts that we need. It's definitely possible (and in fact enjoyable) to use OCaml for building real-world GUIs, but to get a really convenient environment would take some serious backing or a pretty big community effort. (If you're interested in our efforts, follow the link in my profile.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find recent GUI bindings on the old OCaml website. As a rule of thumb, you should consider anything not available through OPAM as outdated. The most "mature" and "wall-supported" bindings for OCaml seem to be LablGtk found here: http://lablgtk.forge.ocamlcore.org/

Answer (score 1):

Many people these days consider that the only GUI "library" that's not outdated is the Web. Whatever your stance on that matter, it's good to know that web is a portable alternative to traditional GUI, and that there are very serious libraries and tools available to program for the web with OCaml (from Ocsigen to Ocamlnet).